# xslt transormation from xml to xml using group by on node and attribute

Tags: xslt

I need help on transforming xml to another xml format using xslt.
Tried using .xsl file below but its not working, appreciate help.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method ="xml" indent ="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="Mappings/Source/MapToType/MapTo/*">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Source" group-by="name">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is source XML

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <Mappings version="1.0">
   <Source name="testA" type="testType" reg="Good">
    <MapToType type="Tiger">
        <MapTo name="Org" reg="Ver1.0"/>
    </MapToType>
   </Source>
  <Source name="testB" type="testType" reg="Good">
    <MapToType type="Tiger">
        <MapTo name="Org2" reg="Ver2.0"/>
    </MapToType>
  </Source>
  <Source name="testA" type="testType" reg="Good">
    <MapToType type="Tiger">
        <MapTo name="Org3" reg="Ver3.0"/>
    </MapToType>
   </Source>
</Mappings>
```

Output expecting like below.

```
 <Mappings version="1.0">
 <Source name="testA" type="testType" reg="Good">
    <MapToType type="Tiger">
        <MapTo name="Org" reg="Ver1.0"/>
        <MapTo name="Org3" reg="Ver3.0"/>
    </MapToType>
  </Source>
  <Source name="testB" type="testType" reg="Good">
    <MapToType type="Tiger">
       <MapTo name="Org2" reg="Ver2.0"/>
    </MapToType>
  </Source>
  </Mappings>
```

Anybody has solution to how to write a condition to display as output.xml?

Comment: "Not working"... maybe share with an [edit] what you mean by this?

Comment: Since you haven't said anything about XSLT versions, and since you've used an XSLT 2.0 construct in a stylesheet labelled as version="1.0", my guess is that you haven't worked out whether you are using a 1.0 or a 2.0 processor. Now, if instead of saying that your code "isn't working", you had told us the manner in which it is failing, we could probably have confirmed or dismissed that suspicion straight away.

Answer (score 2):

First note, `xsl:for-each-group` is an XSLT 2.0 command, so you should really make sure you are using a processor that can process XSLT 2.0

Anyway, one reason it is not working is because when you do `<xsl:for-each-group select="Source" group-by="name">`, you are in a template that matches `MapTo`. As the select will be relative to this `MapTo` element, you will be looking for child elements named `Source`, of which there are none.

(EDIT: Or, as Martin Honnen rightly points out in comments, the template actually matches child elements of `MapTo`, not `MapTo` itself, and so won't match anything, and so will never be used....)

You should really change your template to match `Mappings` instead...

```
<xsl:template match="Mappings">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
     <xsl:for-each-group select="Source" group-by="@name">
```

Note, assuming you might have `MapToType` elements with different types within the grouped `Source` elements, you might then need a nested `xsl:for-each-group` within this one.

Try this XSLT....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method ="xml" indent ="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Mappings">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Source" group-by="@name">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/MapToType" group-by="@type">
            <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
             <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/MapTo" />
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, if the `MapToType` will always have the same `type` for each grouped `Source` element, you can simplify the XSLT to this..

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method ="xml" indent ="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Mappings">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Source" group-by="@name">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
          <MapToType>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="MapToType/@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/MapToType/MapTo" />
          </MapToType>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: If you are only using XSLT 1.0, then you need to use a technique called Muenchian Grouping. This will be overwhelming if you are new to XSLT, especially in this case if you have nested grouping which needs to take into account the parent.

Try this XSLT then:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method ="xml" indent ="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="Sources" match="Source" use="@name" />
  <xsl:key name="MapToTypes" match="MapToType" use="concat(../@name, @type)" />

  <xsl:template match="Mappings">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:for-each select="Source[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Sources', @name)[1])]">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
          <xsl:for-each select="key('Sources', @name)/MapToType[generate-id() = generate-id(key('MapToTypes', concat(../@name, @type))[1])]">
            <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
             <xsl:apply-templates select="key('MapToTypes', concat(../@name, @type))/MapTo" />
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYhX

Read up on Muenchian Grouping at http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. Then, read it again. And again....

Comment: The original template has `match="Mappings/Source/MapToType/MapTo/*"` so it matches any child elements of `MapTo` of which there aren't any at all in the input. Otherwise your answer is fine of course.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I am very new to xslt.I tried both above code but getting error Could not find function: current-group.

Comment: I am using XSLT version 1.0 xalan 2.7 only supports XSLT 1.0

Comment: Can you please help with version 1.0

Comment: I've amended my answer to show the XSLT 1.0 solution.